# ¿como debo de bajar la duplicidad de codigo en models de .net?

Tags: c#, vb.net, .net, c#-8.0, dotnetcore

noches o en la hora que veas esto, hoy estaba pensando en un código en el cual tengo varios models con las mismas características o nombres de columnas ejemplo :

```
    namespace baseDatos.DashboardObras.Dtos
    {
        public partial class ObraAppDto
        {
            public int? Pais { get; set; }
            public int? JefeEquipo { get; set; }
            public int? Programa { get; set; }
            public string Nombre { get; set; }
            public string Tramo { get; set; }
            public int? TipoObra { get; set; }
            public string Provincia { get; set; }
    }
}
```

este es el primer modal donde tenemos declarado las variables de la base de datos y lo que puede llegar de ellas
pero el tema es que hay otro model que tiene 1 o 2 columnas distintas pero el resto es igual ejemplo:

```
namespace baseDatos.DashboardObras.Models.Models
{
    public partial class ObraAppTemporal
    {
        public int Oid { get; set; }
        public int? OidObra { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Fecha { get; set; }
        public int? Pais { get; set; }
        public int? JefeEquipo { get; set; }
        public int? Programa { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string Tramo { get; set; }
        public int? TipoObra { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

**donde como podrás ver cambian algunas cosas, pero se usan las mismas columnas generándose una duplicidad de código, alguien podría explicarme como evitar eso y heredar o usar las mismas del otro modal llamándolas en este segundo modal para evitar esa duplicidad de código en los models**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una opción para evitar la duplicación de código en este caso sería crear una clase base que contenga las propiedades que son comunes a ambos modelos, y luego hacer que las dos clases hereden de esa clase base.

Por ejemplo:

```
namespace baseDatos.DashboardObras.Models
{
    public abstract class ObraAppBase
    {
        public int? Pais { get; set; }
        public int? JefeEquipo { get; set; }
        public int? Programa { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string Tramo { get; set; }
        public int? TipoObra { get; set; }
        public string Provincia { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace baseDatos.DashboardObras.Dtos
{
    public partial class ObraAppDto : ObraAppBase
    {
        // Sin necesidad de declarar las propiedades que ya están en la clase base
    }
}

namespace baseDatos.DashboardObras.Models
{
    public partial class ObraAppTemporal : ObraAppBase
    {
        public int Oid { get; set; }
        public int? OidObra { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Fecha { get; set;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias creo que es lo que buscaba válido y te comento

Comment: Me parece que en este caso es mejor que la clase base no sea abstracta